# $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Find $$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}\, dx$$

Comment: Why won't u-substitution work? Try $u = x^3 + 2$ then $du = 3x^2 dx$.

Answer (score 3):

Let

\begin{align*}
u &= \sqrt{x^3 + 2}\\
du &= \frac{3x^{2}}{2\sqrt{x^{3} + 2}}\,dx
\end{align*}

Then the integral reduces to
$$\frac{2}{3} \int du = \frac{2}{3}u + C = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^{3} +2}+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, let $u=x^3+2$, so that $du=3x^2\,dx$, and then $$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+2}}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{3u^{1/2}}\,du=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{u}+C=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^3+2}+C,$$ so a $u$-substitution of course works...

Comment: Yea, I made a typo, this is embarrassing.